# How to call function from viewcontroller in appdelegate? (Swift)

Tags: swift

So basically I am trying to run the function Refresh (Located in ViewController.swift) in AppDelegate.swift. After searching for the better part of 5 hours I can't figure out why this isnt working.
here is my function:

```
    func Refresh(){
    if(Count==0 && QuickActionChecker==true){
        Previous.text=String(TipArray[CountCurrent])
        Current.text=String(TipArray[CountCurrent])
        Deliveries.text="\(Runs)"

    }
    if(Count>0 && QuickActionChecker==true){
        Previous.text=String(TipArray[CountCurrent-1])
        Current.text=String(Total)
        Deliveries.text="\(Runs)"
    }
}
```

In my Appdelegate.swift I have initialized the ViewController by setting it to Main:

```
let Main = ViewController()
```

and here is where I'm attempting to run the function from (force touch quick action from the homescreen):

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    if shortcutItem.type == "com.Sicarix.Ticket.Add5"{
        if(CountCurrent==0){
            TipArray.append(5)
            Count=Count+1
            CountCurrent=CountCurrent+2
            Total=TipArray.reduce(0) {$0+$1}
            Runs=Runs+1
            QuickActionChecker=true
            Main.Refresh()
        }
        else{
            TipArray.append(5)
            Count=Count+1
            CountCurrent=CountCurrent+1
            Total=TipArray.reduce(0) {$0+$1}
            Runs=Runs+1
            QuickActionChecker=true
            Main.Refresh()
        }
    }
}
```

however, when I try to use the shortcut it opens the app to a white screen and stays there. Console is spitting out:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

the code runs fine when I remove the Main.Refresh(), it just doesn't update the labels in my app, hence the need for the function.
Please help, I'm so ready to move on past this bug....
also please bear in mind that I haven't even been coding in swift for a week yet, so please break down what was wrong as best you can. TIA

Comment: How did you define your arrays?

Comment: In Swift the variables and methods names should start with lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

Change your viewController object

```
let nextVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ViewController") as! ViewController
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are instantiating a new `ViewController` using `ViewController()` and that `ViewController` isn't added to your view controller hierarchy.

You need to use your `Storyboard` to instantiate the `ViewController` by using `let mainVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: "nil").instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ViewController") as! ViewController` and make sure your identifier is set up in `Storyboard`.

If you are not using `Storyboard`, another solution is to store the text you want to display on the UI in data source variables and only update those variables in 'AppDelegate', then load the content of those variables onto your labels in 'viewDidLoad' or 'viewWillAppear'.

Comment: when i use the code you provided (let mainVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"ViewController") as! ViewController) it gives me the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'storyboard'

Comment: Just change `storyboard?` to `UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: "nil")`, see my updated answer.

Comment: now im getting this error :(
 terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
and a SIGABRT error in appdelegate when i try to use the quick action

Comment: What's quick action?

Comment: where you force touch an icon and it allows you to pick a quick action

Comment: I can't see `QuickActionChecker` defined in your code, please include the relevant code where you define it.

Comment: var QuickActionChecker:Bool=false

Comment: Try debugging your code, set up an exception breakpoint and check which line exactly is causing the issue and what exact error is thrown.

Comment: it's saying that it doesnt contain a view controller with identifier "ViewController"

Comment: Are these `UILabel`s of `ViewController`? Cause in that case you have to call them by `mainVC.Deliveries`. Also, variable names in `Swift` should start with **lowercase** characters.

Comment: it is a view from a tab bar controller... does that not make it a viewcontroller? I'm sorry, im very new to xcode in general

Comment: it says class: UIView  in the identity inspector on storyboard

Comment: Please include all of your relevant code in your question, with bits and pieces it is really hard to put together what your problem is. See [How to create a Minimal, Verifiable and Complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry... Im kind of learning as we go, I didn't know this 10 minutes ago